# Which areas can be accelerated by FPGA and GPU

Tags: parallel-processing, gpgpu, fpga, hardware-acceleration

I'm trying to accelerate any of my software using FPGA/GPU. I'm little confused to choose among these two. Which areas are suitable for FPGA and which areas are suitable for GPU (like Image processing is suitable for GPUs). Also it'd be good to know the areas which can be accelerated by more than 20x. I'm more interested on GPU as they are cheap and programming is easier compared to FPGA

Comment: Have a look at OpenCL https://www.khronos.org/opencl/

Comment: There shouldn't be any area where you can achive a speedup of 20 and more. If so the measurement methods are not choosen in a fair way. E.g. many CPU - GPU camparisons use C code without any optimizations or only -O1.

Answer (score 0):

Main difference between FPGA and GPU is that in fact today GPGPU is like CPU. It can easily handle pointers, functions and all programming is easy, because CUDA/OpenCL work with some set of C/C++ (for example OpenCL use C99 + some special functions).

FPGA is more hardware oriented. You can define gates and whole logic, which is then faster and there is paralelism, but it's achieved by different means.

---

FPGA is much better in serial operations, when it have constant stream of data (streaming encryption, video decoding,...) and when reprogramming is not casual. You can close FPGA in box and let it do its job only by connecting input, output cables and power supply.

GPGPU is always connected through PCI express and sending program to it is common (games use set of shaders (GPU programs), which are switching quickly), so it is more like batch handling device. Today GPGPU have large ammounts of RAM and cores/multiprocesors so it's really a more like CPU than FPGA.

---

There is one (maybe more, but I can't remember more) thing, that FPGA will be a lot faster. I don't know about any need for this (other than (de)crypting), but it's huge ammounts of different bit operations. GPUs are specialized at working with floats and ints (32 bit floating point and integer values), but they are quite slow when you have to do some binary magic. Simply by utilizing FPGA architecture, this binary magic can be done in paralel in one tick.

In GPU, you have to divide each binary operation (AND, OR, XOR,...), study in which order they have to be done.

---

Tl,dr: If you dont have specific need for FPGA, choose GPGPU.